# Audio stutter when performing simple tasks (Win 8)

Tags: windows-8, google-chrome, audio, performance

I've been struggling with frequent audio problems in the form of sound stuttering when, for instance, a new Chrome tab is opened, or a web page is being scrolled, when a window is minimised/maximised, etc.

My laptop is not brand new, but it's less than two years old: Intel i5-4210U @ 1,7 GHz, 8 GB RAM, SSD, Windows 8.1.

I've played with the audio drivers - downloaded the latest ones from Realtek, then got the ones from Asus' support page, even though those were older. None of those seem to have any effect for long: initially, after the old drivers have been removed and the new ones installed, playback is alright. But in a day or two, it starts stuttering again.

Every program is affected, too: radio streaming in Chrome or in a dedicated radio app (Screamer), KMPLayer, Media Player Classic.

Does anyone have any idea how I can sort this out, please?

Thank you!

Comment: This looks like DPC issues. Install the WPT (part of the Win10 SDK: https://dev.windows.com/en-us/downloads/windows-10-sdk), run WPRUI.exe,  load and check this profile inside WPRUI.exe (**Add Profiles**) https://www.dropbox.com/s/8rl4r784kvnhypf/Multimedia_WPRP.WPRP?dl=1 and click on **Start**. Now capture 1 minute of the audio issues. After 1 minute click on **Save**. Zip the large ETL file (+ NGENPDB fodler) into 1 zip, upload the zip (OneDrive, dropbox, google drive) and post the share link here. I'll try to analyze it

Comment: have you captured the trace while seeing the audio stuttering?